# How to write a Numba function used both in CPU mode and in CUDA device mode?

Tags: cuda, numba

I want to write a Numba function used both in CPU mode and in CUDA device mode. Of course, I can write two identical functions with and without the cuda.jit decorator. For example:

```
from numba import cuda, njit

@njit("i4(i4, i4)")
def func_cpu(a, b)
    return a + b

@cuda.jit("i4(i4, i4)", device=True)
def func_gpu(a, b)
    return a + b
```

But it is ugly in software engineering. Is there a more elegant way, i.e., combining the codes in one function?

Comment: You do understand how decorators actually work? This is trivial if you do

Comment: Why is this question down voted? Seems pretty reasonable to me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A decorator is essentially a function, that takes a function as the input, and also returns a (often modified) function as the output. The addition of arguments and keywords arguments as done with Numba makes it slightly more complicated (internally), but you can think of it as a nested function where the outer one again returns a decorator.

So instead of using it as a decorator like you do now (with the `@`), you can just call it as any function and capture the output. And the output will then be a callable function as well.

This allows writing your function in pure Python, and then apply as many "decorators" on it as you'd like. For example:

```py
from numba import cuda, njit

def func_py(a, b)
    return a + b

func_njit = njit("i4(i4, i4)")(func_py)
func_gpu = cuda.jit("i4(i4, i4)", device=True)(func_py)

assert func_py(4, 3) == func_njit(4, 3)
assert func_py(4, 3) == func_gpu(4, 3)
```

Comment: It works. Thank you! One more question: why do we need the signature twice for func_gpu?

Comment: Sorry you don't, accidentally pasted it incorrectly I think. I tested it with the vectorize decorator because I don't have cuda hardware, and then swapped it back to what you mentioned in the OP. I've edited the answer to correct it.